# Too much space around quote environment

Tags: spacing, memoir, quoting

Sometimes, LaTeXput extra white lines around my `\begin{quote}`.
I use just the basic `memoir` class without any customization.
Any hint?

Comment: Would you like to prepare a short [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/) that shows the effect?

Comment: What do you mean by *extra lines* ? Are you leaving empty lines before the `quote`?

Comment: I mean extra vertical spaces, before and after the quote env.

Comment: Try adding `\raggedbottom` and `\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}` to your preamble.  If that doesn't work, please provide a full, but minimal example.  (This is always advisable, and always polite and helpful to people who want to help *you*.)  Note there is also `\raggedbottomsection`, which selectively sets `\raggedbottom` on pages where a new section is called.

Answer (score 2):

This can all depend on how you're setting things up.

If you stick with the basic parameter values for shaping and handling paragraphs then the spacing shouldn't be too bad:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{quote}
\lipsum[1]
\end{quote}
\lipsum[10]

\end{document}
```

[image]

But if you start tweaking with the general formatting such as in this next example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength\parskip{2ex}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{quote}
\lipsum[1]
\end{quote}
\lipsum[10]

\end{document}
```

Then the spacing gets a bit out of hand.  Generally it is advised not to tamper with the value of `\parskip`.

Since you haven't provided a MWE (yet), I can only guess what's going on with your document.  Nevertheless, there are a few things you can try.

First you can add some negative `\vspace`

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\setlength\parskip{2ex}
%\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]
\vspace{-2ex}
\begin{quote}
\lipsum[1]
\end{quote}
\vspace{-2ex}
\lipsum[10]

\end{document}
```

Personally, I wouldn't be happy with this solution.  The extra spacing around the quote environment helps set it apart from the rest of the text.

Another solution would be to define your own quote environment.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newenvironment{myquote}{%%
  \begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt]
  \item[]}{\end{itemize}}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{myquote}
\lipsum[1]
\end{myquote}
\lipsum[10]

\end{document}
```

I've loaded the `enumitem` package to facilitate the spacing before and after the environment.  And, certainly, you can set `topsep` to a value which gives you the aesthetic appearance you're looking for.

Comment: I can assure that I did not put any strange setting. The text body is full of footnotes, sometimes very long footnotes, and in some page I get many extra vertical space around the quote. Yes, vspace with negative value could be a solution...

Comment: Setting `\parskip` to some value (such as `2ex`) isn't necessarily strange.  For some documents it may be appropriate (though most on this site will disagree with me on that point).  But changing `\parskip` can have unintended effect since its value is used in a variety of different structures.

Comment: With \vsapce is quite impossibile to control the environment "padding"...

Comment: The `\vspace` solution is really only appropriate for tweaking things in a particular context, not a general approach.  I would suggest defining your own quote environment if it's every occurrence of `quote` that's bothering you.

Comment: My suspicion is @giuseppe's document, which has lots of footnotes, is (implicitly) typeset with `\flushbottom` (the default in a two-sided document), which will take advantage of environments like `quote` to fulfill the objective of having the textblock align at the bottom of the page (i.e., by 'stretching' the whitespace around the environment).  The easiest solution, if I'm right, is to use `\raggedbottom`, which does not, however, end up looking too great.  The other option is to make the footnotes be typeset `flushbottom` (e.g., with `\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}`.